# Error showing no such file or directory when running snort.conf

Tags: networking

Its about snort , where i cant run the snort.conf and showing there is no such file or directory. How to solve that issue?
The image is a snippet of vmware virtual machine where I have found a problem of a snort networking

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since `snort` is a very configurable tool, there's no reasonable default configuration, so you have to create `snort.conf` yourself. Start by reading `man snort`, look at https://www.snort.org/snort3

Comment: I have gone through the site https://www.snort.org/documents  but the video about snort install and configuration is not working because of the updates of snort. Like I am getting an error. Actually I was going through LinuxBasicsFor Hackers by OTW where snort.conf is used for head and tail for file viewing. But I can't even figure out why snort.conf is not working and I am still clueless. Can I skip it, for now, to proceed with the rest of the chapters as I am a BEGINNER I can't even figure out sometimes which path should be followed in the snort config issue.

Comment: I haven't read it, but I suspect a book entitled "LinuxBasicsFor Hackers by OTW" is not the best beginner's book.

Comment: Can you suggest one for a beginner Linux Book?

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm not up-to-date with books for beginners. Try The Linux Documentation Project at https://tldp.org/ (seem offline for some reason at 18:27 EDT 31 Mar 2024) retry later.

Comment: @AK-007 Try https://tldp.org/guides.html and search for "Introduction to Linux - A Hands on Guide"